# Can roslyn generate enums?

Tags: c#, enums, roslyn

So, I feel like it's possible, but i don't have the chops to put it together. I have lookup tables (with ID and Name fields). I have enums that I keep in sync with the lookups. What I'd like is to make a list of SQL tables, and have roslyn create the enums during/before compile. this way I know my enums are always in sync, and it's one more thing off my plate.

Could someone out there show me the way, or tell me why it would be a bad idea? I feel like the solution isn't really a lot of code...

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can do this even without using Roslyn. It sounds like regular code generation to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you create enums with roslyn;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var member1 = Syntax.EnumMemberDeclaration(
            identifier: Syntax.Identifier("Member1")
            );

        var declaration = Syntax.EnumDeclaration(
            identifier: Syntax.Identifier("MyEnum"),
            modifiers: Syntax.TokenList(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)),
            members: Syntax.SeparatedList(member1)
            );

        Console.WriteLine(declaration.Format());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

this returns:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Member1
}
```

Now to your question, I don't know if this is what you really need.

First I think there is not yet any built in functionality to do this at precompile, so you'd need to create a console exe and call it in your prebuild events.

So at this point probably it is a better idea to do this manually via code generation and not on every build, unless these tables are changing very frequently.

An in this case you don't really need roslyn to do it for you, you can just spit it out with any code generation software, or roll your own...

Comment: I think this is a good head start for me. I like how clean the syntax is. I could really expound upon this and create what I want, I believe. Is there a consensus that there's already something out there that does this? I feel like you've broght me halfway to a tool that I'd use in all future projects...

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. At work we do what you mention (although not in a prebuild event) by using SqlServer management libraries plus some templates to generate enum and immutable classes representing the tables that then we extend. Now, that is not as fun as playing with a new technology, so if your goal is to learn roslyn and have some fun with it, I'd say go ahead!

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, but you probably already now, is that roslyn is a CTP, and it will change in future releases thus most probably breaking your code. So keep that in mind when using this in *real* life

Comment: Code no longer works as provided. members: Syntax.SeparatedList(member1) Produces a can not infer from usage error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code updated for the current version of Roslyn and also shows adding attributes and values to the enum items.

```
        public EnumDeclarationSyntax GenerateEnum()
    {
        var loanPurpose = new[]
        {
            "Business Launching",
            "HomePurchase",
            "HomeImprovement"

        };
        var enumDescriptions = new[]
        {
            "Launch a new business",
            "Buy a home",
            "Make home improvements"
        };
        var i = 0;
        var members = new List<EnumMemberDeclarationSyntax>();
        foreach (var item in loanPurpose)
        {
            var attribute = SyntaxFactory.Attribute(
                SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Description"));
            var attributeArgument = SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgument(
                SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(
                    SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                    SyntaxFactory.Literal(enumDescriptions[i ])));
            attribute = attribute.WithArgumentList(
                SyntaxFactory.AttributeArgumentList(
                    SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(attributeArgument)));
            var attributes = SyntaxFactory.SingletonList(
                SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(SyntaxFactory
                    .SingletonSeparatedList(attribute)));
            var objectCreationExpression = SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(
                SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression,
                    SyntaxFactory.Literal(i)));
            var member = SyntaxFactory.EnumMemberDeclaration(attributes, 
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier(item),
                objectCreationExpression);
            members.Add(member);
            i++;
        }
        var declaration = SyntaxFactory.EnumDeclaration
            (new SyntaxList<AttributeListSyntax>(),
            baseList: null,
            identifier: SyntaxFactory.Identifier("LoanPurpose"),
            modifiers: SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)),
            members: SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(members)
            );
        return declaration;
    }
```

The syntax for adding the attributes gets a little awkward but I find that I often need some attributes added.   You probably already have the data for the attributes and values in the lookup tables driving the code generation.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer provided by Sebastian 6 years ago likely used to work but no longer does. 
New set of sample code to accomplish the same thing as of 18/12/2017

```
EnumMemberDeclarationSyntax member1 = EnumMemberDeclaration(identifier: Identifier("Member1"));

var members =new SyntaxNodeOrToken[]{member1};

var declaration = EnumDeclaration(
            identifier: Identifier("MyEnum")).WithMembers(
            members: SeparatedList< EnumMemberDeclarationSyntax>(members));
```